# Android. Show different content based on original Market country

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to show different content based on Play Market country / determine from which regional market user downloaded it from.

eg. User downloaded app from German play market - show German content, User downloaded app from French play market - show French content. etc.
So user can be anywhere - but get Play store country, NOT the user's geolocation.

Comment: You can add translations according to the locale. Look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) for more info regarding that

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by different content

Comment: No no no
It's not about locale, it's about content
eg. posts, photos, articles

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from Google Play console:

select your app
then from left menu, extend "Store presence" dropdown menu
then select "**Custom store listings**"
click "Create custom store listing"
click "+ Country" and chose specific country(s)

[screenshot from Google Play console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99qo2.png)